# SSH Connection timed out on EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssh, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to secure my apache with `Let's Encrypt` on Ubuntu 18.04,

I ran these commands:

> $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot 
> $ sudo apt install python-certbot-apache 
> $ sudo ufw enable 
> $ sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'

After the last command, The terminal froze, so I decided to close it and reconnect hoping it would really reconnect. 
Unfortunately, it returns with a message saying:

> ssh: connect to host <...some public ipv4 DNS> port 22: Connection timed out

I checked the security groups to see if `SSH` is set to `Anywhere` and yes its set.

My guess is I messed up the `ufw` configs(or maybe not), but I can't confirm it because I cant ssh to my ec2 instance.

**EDIT: 

I tried stopping and starting the instance, causing it to change its public ip address, which I still cant ssh to :(**

Comment: This is probably going to be better to ask on [superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Oh shoot my bad, I'll still leave it here hoping someone knows the workarounds :)

Comment: You've likely locked yourself out of your machine.  I don't really feel that `ufw` is needed when using AWS but to recover, see [this link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=686376).

Comment: Did you try to use the console from within your AWS account to connect to the host?

Comment: yes, no luck. created a new isntance
I can charge this to my experience, to always backup anything. Luckily the content is not large yet.

Comment: As well, generally, it's good practice to be prepared to rebuild an instance quickly.  They may not last forever.

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be because `ufw` by default doesn't have `allow 22` rule set, so before you enable `ufw` try running `sudo ufw allow 22` or `sudo ufw allow ssh`.

To allow ssh before enabling `ufw` try running the below command which adds the rule to `/etc/ufw/user.rules`

`sudo ufw allow ssh`

So when user enables `ufw` it reads the already existing rules from the file, and doesn't terminate or block the user out of the access.

And then running the following commands will make it easy for the user to access the instance without any issues.

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 443
sudo ufw status
```

However, when coming to cloud provisioned instances, it's more likely and easy to  play with **`security groups`** which would give a higher level of access to play with a specific instance and their corresponding rules.